# Изменить данные из другой модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-model

Есть классы:

```
class Printer(Product):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Категория")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Имя в локальной сети", unique=True)
    printerModel = models.ForeignKey(PrinterModel, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Модель")
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Производитель")
    isColor = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Цветной")
    printerStatus = models.ForeignKey(PrinterStatus, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Статус")
    printerLocation = models.ForeignKey(Room, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Месторасположение")
    date_create = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Описание", blank=True)

class PrinterSchedule(Schedule):
    printer = models.ForeignKey(Printer,models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Принтер")
    status = models.ForeignKey(PrinterStatus,models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Статус")
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room,models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Место расположение")
```

Каким образом можно сделать что бы при изменении в классе `Printer` информация записалась в таблицу `PrinterSchedule`? Необходимо, что бы было известно статус и место расположения в настоящее время поэтому соответствующие поля находятся в самом классе `Printer`.

Comment: вы пишете, что "статус и место расположения ... находятся в самом классе Printer", но они у вас в PrinterSchedule...

Comment: Это старый код я скопировал. Но в новой версии есть сюда не скопировать.